# Cloud platform for machine control systems

Tags: security, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible tp use google cloud platform to build control systems for industrial machines? I like google cloud plarform including the great community support.

Is it recommended to use google cloud platform is it better to look for specialised cloud platforms for industrial applications? Is it possible to build a web application on google app engine, which provide security for industrial control apllications?

Comment: the main point of appengine is scalability.  why would you want to scale such system?

Comment: Because such system could control hundreds or thousands machines. But there are not millions of user.

Comment: seems risky to unnecesarily connect them to the internet unless they must.

Comment: That's why I asked for security. Each machine has a local control device. The local control device collect data from the machine and other data sources. To control the local system, I need to make load forecasts and so on. These things I would like to do in a backend of a cloud  application. The cloud application gets a lot of data from the local devices and other data like weather information. The app will combine each data source, analyse the data, make a control decision and give a command back to local system. With the data, there is also the opportunity for predictive analytics functions.

Comment: its best if you only allow outbound to internet, to send data to an appengine and/or bigquery or other cloud services. that is a fine scenario.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with “only allow outbound to internet“?

Comment: Ok I got it :P But after analyzing the data, I have to send a control command back to the local control device.

Comment: you could either poll or use websockets/gcm. gcm is great because it handles queueing. question is really too broad for s.o. but just remember stuxnet